# How to exclude text between two patterns in the same line

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file with the input

```
sp|O34439|YFLP_BACSU UPF0065 protein YflP OS=Bacillus subtilis (strain 168) GN=yflP PE=3 SV=2
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEK
sp|Q44018|YGB7_CUPNE UPF0065 protein in gbd 5'region OS=Cupriavidus necator PE=3 SV=1
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENK
```

and need to get this output:

```
sp|O34439|YFLP_Bacillus subtilis
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEK
sp|Q44018|YGB7_Cupriavidus necator
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENK
```

So, I need to exclude everything between the pattern `>|......|....` and `OS=....................` (If I can exclude the `OS=` and leave `,` even better) and exclude anything after the second pattern in the same line.

Comment: Its here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/extract-value-between-two-search-patterns-on-same-line

Comment: This post show how to get things between two patterns, but not how to exclude them as far as I could understand. I might be mistaken, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming lots of consistency, you could use something like...

```
$ sed -r 's/([^ ]+\|[^ ]+\|[^_]+_)[^_]+ .* OS=([^ ]+ [^ ]+) .*/\1\2/' file
sp|O34439|YFLP_Bacillus subtilis
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEK
sp|Q44018|YGB7_Cupriavidus necator
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENK
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `(some chars)` remember `some chars` to reference later with `\1` etc
- `[^ ]+` at least one non-space character (`[^_]+` is at least one non-underscore character)
- `\|` literal `|` since in ERE `|` is used for alternation
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `\1\2` back references to saved patterns

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\).*=\([A-Z][a-z ]*\).*/\1_\2/' test
```

does what you want for file `test` and writes the output to the terminal:

```
> sed 's/\([^_]*\).*=\([A-Z][a-z ]*\).*/\1_\2/' test
sp|O34439|YFLP_Bacillus subtilis 
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEK
sp|Q44018|YGB7_Cupriavidus necator 
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENK
```

Add `> filename` to the end of the command to save the output in file `filename` instead.

### Explanation

- `\(.*_\)` take everything until the first underscore, save it as group 1
- `.*=` take everything until the first equal sign

  - replace by `.*OS=` to take everything until `OS=`
- `\([A-Z][a-z ]*\)` take one upper case letter and all the following lower case letters and spaces, save it as group 2

  - replace  with `\([^ ]*[ ][^ ]*\)` to search for a string with exactly one space in it
- `.*` (preceding space not displayed here!) take a space and the rest of the line
- `\1\2` group 1 followed by group 2

Comment: Thank you for this, but as I did the output was  >sp|O34439|YFLP_yflP
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEKGWKYVNKSSKQTISMTSSLILSNDLLGQSKLKMSDFTPLAILSKEWQTVALPKGSALTNGKDVLNEINMHPGKVRIGFAPGFGNDDQLSFVRAADMYGIDPFDIQFSQYDSSEQLIQALIRHEIEAASMTLSEAKPYERNGDITLAAVTSDKRLPGFPNVPTWKEQGIPFVFSHWRGILGPKNMSEEEISYWDQALKKVTSSPEWKRKINEQDWESFYLNSRETKRFLEEQSAFYQSIMTGN
>sp|Q44018|YGB7_Cupriavidus necator
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENKPGAGGVLPAQMMQSTAPDGYTLAQVAMPVYRLPYTTKINWDPVKDLNYIINLAGYSFGLVVPADSPIKTMQEYIAYAKANPGKLTYGSPGSM

Comment: @LeonardoTRosa I corrected it, the first one had a typo. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*_)[A-Z].*=(\w+)\s{1,2}(\w+)\s{1,2}.*\s.*/\1\2 \3/g' file.txt
sp|O34439|YFLP_Bacillus subtilis    
MKKSIILLNILLIFMQGDIRQAAAPRLPDGPIEIVVPAEPSGGWDVTAQAIQSVLRQKQIVKDDVHIVYKSGGGGEK
sp|Q44018|YGB7_Cupriavidus necator
MQRRHFIARAGIAAATAALGLAAMPAQAQADKFPQRPIRLVIGYTAGGSTDIPFRVLADNASKILGQPVIVENK
```

Explanation:

- `(.*_)` - Return every thing till first upper case letter
- `.*=`   - Take till equal sign
- `(\w+)\s{1,2}` - Return first word before `1-2` spaces
- `(\w+)\s{1,2}` - Same as above
- `.*\s.*` - Get all till space and all after that
- `\1\2 \3` - Return captured groups

Comment: @Zanna the `*?=` is needed to return groups `2` and `3`, and the first can be left out

Comment: @Zanna I agree with `*` but best test it [here](https://regex101.com/) to see what I mean

Comment: Oh I see, it's lazy or non-greedy (in perl style regex I think)... But does `sed` recognise that notation? I [don't think it does](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25397413/) hmm. BTW your final `g` is also superfluous, since we aren't matching the pattern more than once.

Comment: @Zanna ok I see not an expert on it yet. But updated answer, thanks.